# How to create function for POST JSON parsing in Swift

Tags: json, swift, function

In my project i have all POST method JSON URL's, so i need to create one separate function.. Now I want to use that function in all viewcontrollers with differnt urls and parameters... but i am unable to create separate function for JSON

I am writing same code for all viewcontrollrs with different `url`s and `jsonpostParameters` like below

```
  func loginService(){
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://e/api/login")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let jsonpostParameters = LoginData(jsonrpc: "2.0", params: (PostLogin(email: nameTf.text!, password: passwordTf.text!, device_id: "2")))
        
    do {
        let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(jsonpostParameters)
        request.httpBody = jsonBody
    } catch {
        print("Error while encoding parameter: \(error)")
    }
        let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { [self] (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let data = data else {return}
            
        do{
            
            let jsonModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(Employees.self, from: data)

            print("new model \(jsonModel.result)")
            
                            
            DispatchQueue.main.sync{
                if jsonModel.error != nil{
                let controller = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Your email is not verified", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                controller.addAction(ok)
                controller.addAction(cancel)

                self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
                
                
            else{
                
                let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as? ProfileViewController
                vc?.userData = jsonModel
                vc?.tokenKey = jsonModel.result!.token

                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
                
            }
            }
            print("the error is \(error)")
        }catch{ print("Error while decoding: \(error.localizedDescription)") }
        }
        task.resume()
    
}
```

how to write all code in one function with different `urls` and different `jsonpostParameters` to call that function in all view controllers, pls do help with code

Comment: `func loginService()` You have a function with zero parameters. Put parameters there, like func loginService(urlString: String, bodyParameters: Data)`, and call it: loginService(urlString: "https://e/api/login", bodyParameters: jsonpostParameters)`?

Comment: @Larme, how to handle different viewcontroller's success and error response with function

Comment: @Larme how to handle response and send parameters.. pls post answer

Comment: Use a closure to manage that. See the answer, the `failureBlock` andn `successblock` (even if its naming is too much Objective-C, the logic is the same).

Comment: @Larme, I am unable to understand  the answer, pls post your answer.. first time i am working with `completionHandler`

Comment: In reality, when you are doing `dataTask(with: request) { ... }`, the `{ ... }` that's already a completionhandler/closure/block just mimic that into your parameter method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class NetworkService: NSObject{


static let manager = NetworkService()

func  loginService(_ urlPath: String, _ params: [String: Any]?, method: String, successBlock onSuccess: @escaping ((Your result model) -> Void),
                   failureBlock onFailure: @escaping ((Error) -> Void)){
    guard let url = URL(string: urlPath) else {
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = method
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { [self] (data, response, error) in
        
        guard let data = data else {return}
        if success{
            onSuccess(pass data to VC)
        }else{
            onFailure(pass error)
        }
    }
    task.resume
}
}
```

Call the service from Viewcontroller like

```
 NetworkService.manager. loginService(urlPath, nil, method: "POST") { (success) in
     //success code here
} failureBlock: { (failure) in
     //Handle failure
}
```

Comment: could you answer this in detail.. i mean according to my question.. i am unable to understand.. i working first time with completionHandler